# PHP-FPM: pm.process_idle_timeout vs php_admin_value[max_execution_time]

Tags: php

I have set the FCGI idle timeout value to 120 with `-idle-timeout 120` in my Apache site configuration to make sure Apache doesn't time out before my php scripts are finished executing, but now I'm wondering what the difference is between setting `php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 120` and `pm.process_idle_timeout = 120s` in a php-fpm .conf file?

Does one override the other? Is there a difference? Do I need to set both if I want to make sure my scripts don't time out before the length of time I specify?

Any explanation or reference would be helpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the comments from the file `php-fpm.conf.default`: `pm.process_idle_timeout` has nothing to do with script execution. It defines the time a spawned FPM child has to be idle (i.e. not handle a request) before it will be killed. This does not affect script execution in any way (not even sleep()).

[PHP: Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time):
The PHP INI setting `max_execution_time` defines the maximum process time (CPU time) in seconds after which script execution will be halted.
*Note: Last time I checked (2 years ago), this did not apply to Windows where the elapsed real time counts.*

Comment: So for example, in accordance with the way I'm interpreting your answer, say that the php fpm setting `process_idle_timeout` was set to `10s`, and the php ini value `max_execution_time` got set to `120`, if a request came in that took 20 seconds to execute, the following would take place: an FPM process would get spawned, that script would run fully since it's well under the 120 second cap, and then that same FPM process would wait another 10 seconds for more requests to come in before killing itself, but if another request comes in, that timer resets and so on and so forth.. is that correct?

Comment: @bruchowski Exactly :)

Comment: Your expected PHP-FPM equivalent to PHP's `max_execution_time` is [`request_terminate_timeout`](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#request-terminate-timeout).

Comment: @tanius your comment saved me after hours of searching and experimenting. Thanks.